# Share USB over network

Tags: raspbian, usb

I'm looking for a free method to share an USB device over network. I got a RaspberryPi (raspbian) which has an USB device connected. I want to be able to receive from and send commands to this device from my debian server.

I've tried [remserial](http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/) but I'm unable to connect the client to the server. I've also tried [VirtualHere](https://www.virtualhere.com/) but it crashed.

I found this [solution](http://www.seraphiccorp.com/2014/08/usbip-raspberry-pi-kinect-et-sarah/) but it seem to be very long.

Do you know some free solution to do it?

EDIT :
so i tried USBIP but i got some trouble :

```
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ zcat /proc/config.gz |grep USBIP
CONFIG_USBIP_CORE=m
CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HCD=m
CONFIG_USBIP_HOST=m
# CONFIG_USBIP_DEBUG is not set
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo modprobe usbip-core
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo modprobe usbip-host
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo usbipd -D

pi@raspberrypi /boot $ usbip list -l
Local USB devices
=================
- busid 1-1 (0424:9514)
     1-1:1.0 -> hub
- busid 1-1.1 (0424:ec00)
     1-1.1:1.0 -> smsc95xx
- busid 1-1.3 (0403:6010)
     1-1.3:1.0 -> unknown
     1-1.3:1.1 -> unknown
- busid 1-1.4 (04f2:1126)
     1-1.4:1.0 -> usbhid
- busid 1-1.5 (04f2:1125)
     1-1.5:1.0 -> usbhid
     1-1.5:1.1 -> usbhid

pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo usbip --debug  bind -b 1-1.3
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:134:[run_command]
running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:162:[unbind_other]
1-1.3:1.0 -> unknown
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:162:[unbind_other]
1-1.3:1.1 -> unknown
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/utils.c:65:[modify_match_busid]
write "add 1-1.3" to /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host/match_busid
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:101:[bind_usbip]
bind driver at 1-1.3:1.0 failed
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:101:[bind_usbip]
bind driver at 1-1.3:1.1 failed
usbip: error: could not bind device to usbip-host
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/utils.c:65:[modify_match_busid]
write "del 1-1.3" to /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host/match_busid
  pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo usbip --debug  bind -b 1-1.3:1.1
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:134:[run_command]
  running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:143:[unbind_other]
  problem getting device attributes: No such file or directory
usbip: error: could not unbind driver from device on busid 1-1.3:1.1
pi@raspberrypi /boot $
```

what could it be ?

Comment: What is the USB device?

Comment: Let's try `usbip` ... It is on Raspbian's repo...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the USB device is an embedded system,i'll take a look at USBIP

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to send and receive serial data from the embedded system, **ser2net** (in the Raspbian repo) may be all you need. I'm using it to communicate with Cisco routers over direct USB and USB-to-serial converters.

Comment: Last question, it's working on my virtual machine, but i'm trying to run it on my real server (vm is ubuntu, server is debian) on ubuntu it work well , i connect the system to the port using :
sudo socat pty,link=/dev/virtualcom0,raw tcp:myip:3333& 
So to test ser2net with the server, i create a SSH connection between the VM and the server, use the same socat command but when i list my /dev/ i can't see the virtual port
it create the process i can see the :
[1] 9089 
but if i send another command it just stop [1] + stopped "socat command"

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding what you mean: You have the server connected to the embedded device via USB. You are running ser2net on the server to connect from the network. You are using socat on a remote machine to read the serial data. And you are not finding the virutal device socat creates on the remote computer. Is that correct? I'm not sure why "SSH connection between the VM and the server" matters in this case. Are the server and remote computer both on the same IP subnet or are you connecting from another location?

Comment: I created an answer because it's too long